# Linux - Launch recordmydestop during specific time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, recordmydesktop

I have some trouble using "recordmydesktop" (capturing video of the computer screen) in command line.
I have a shell script that find the ID of a specific window and launch recordmydesktop with the window ID.
Here is my script :

```
recordmydesktop --no-sound --delay 3 --windowid $(xwininfo -name "NAME" | sed -n 's/.*Window id: \([0-9a-fx]\+\).*/\1/p')
```

NAME is the name of the window to record. 
The thing is, I want to record during X seconds, and in the man help, there is no options to do that.
The app can be stopped with "Ctrl+C", but I want to make it automatically after X seconds.

Any idea ?

Thanks for reading me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

recordmydesktop --no-sound --delay 3 --windowid $(xwininfo -name "NAME" | sed -n 's/.*Window id: \([0-9a-fx]\+\).*/\1/p') &

sleep $1; pkill recordmydesktop
```

or if you need Ctrl+c:

```
sleep $1; pkill --signal=SIGINT recordmydesktop
```

value of pause - first scripts parameter